# How do I find the title of a textbox whose border is "Titled Border"?

Tags: java, border

I can set the title for a titled border for a `JTextField` `c` easily enough.

```
   c.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
```

The documentation says to use `getTitle()` to find the contents of the title, but I can't find any example or working combination of what seems natural. None of the below will even compile:

```
   c.getBorder().getTitle();

   c.getTitle();

   Border b = null;
...
   b = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new LineBorder(BLACK, 2),title);
   c.setBorder(b);
   b = c.getBorder();
   b.getTitle();
```

How do I get the String contents of the title of a `JTextField` whose border type is `createTitledBorder` ?

Comment: @gla3dr--Good point; I know type was not `createTitledBorder` since that's a method, but I didn't think of making b have type `TitledBorder`. But as it happens, I can't declare b to be of type `TitledBorder` (in the big picture) some cells are of type `TitledBorder` and some of type `LineBorder` and all cells are passed to a method that needs to distinguish. So I'm going to start a new thread about that, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border type is not `createTitledBorder`. That is just the name of the static factory method you are using. It returns a `TitledBorder`. Calling `getBorder()` on the JTextField only returns a border of type `Border`, which does not have the `getTitle()` method, since not all borders have titles.

You need to have a reference to the border that is of type `TitledBorder` so that Java knows that the border has a title:

```
TitledBorder b = null;
...
b = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new LineBorder(BLACK, 2),title);
c.setBorder(b);
b = (TitledBorder)c.getBorder();
b.getTitle();
```

or, if you don't want to keep a reference of type `TitledBorder`, you could do this:

```
Border b = null;
...
b = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new LineBorder(BLACK, 2),title);
c.setBorder(b);
b = c.getBorder();
( (TitledBorder)b ).getTitle();
```

---

**EDIT**
Here is a less verbose way of doing what you have done in your posted answer:

```
Border b;
String title;

b = c.getBorder();
if(b instanceof TitledBorder)
{
    title = ( (TitledBorder)b ).getTitle();
}
```

Comment: I think my comment to your first answer still applies. For cells that are NOT of type `TitledBorder` I get `ClassCastException: javax.swing.border.LineBorder cannot be cast to javax.swing.border.TitledBorder`, but maybe this is a case for using `instance of`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title");
c.setBorder(border);
```

You could then call the getTitle method using something like

```
System.out.println(border.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
Border b;
TitledBorder tb;
String title;

    b = c.getBorder();
    if(b instanceof TitledBorder)
    {
      c.getBorder();
      tb = (TitledBorder)c.getBorder();
      title = tb.getTitle();
    }
```

No matter what type of border `c` has, *IF* it's `TitledBorder`, I get the title as advertised. If not, proceed as usual.

Thanks, gla3dr, for the tip.

Does anyone see a less verbose way of accomplishing the task?

Comment: Hey, I added an edit to my post with a less verbose method of doing what you have here. You won't have to store the border as a `TitledBorder`, and it brings the body of the if statement down to one line.